# Missing class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle, proguard

Recently I have upgraded my gradle version from 7.2 to 8.1. After the upgradation, I am facing

```
Missing class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension 
(referenced from: java.lang.String 
io.agora.base.internal.Logging.getStackTraceString(java.lang.Throwable) and 18 other 
contexts)

Missing class reactor.blockhound.integration.BlockHoundIntegration (referenced from: 
reactor.core.scheduler.ReactorBlockHoundIntegration)
```

This happens when I try to sign my build. I am using pro-guard rules which may be causing the issue.

What I tried so far

- Upgraded to the Latest version of Agora (4.2.6)
- Updated Gradle version to **com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.0'**
- Updated reactor version to  **'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-
  reactor:1.7.1'**

**Proguard rules:**

```html
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}
-keep,allowobfuscation interface com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName
# for glide
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public class * extends com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.ImageHeaderParser$** {
  **[] $VALUES;
  public *;
}


# for eventbus
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe <methods>;
}
-keep enum org.greenrobot.eventbus.ThreadMode { *; }

# And if you use AsyncExecutor:
-keepclassmembers class * extends org.greenrobot.eventbus.util.ThrowableFailureEvent {
    <init>(java.lang.Throwable);
}



-useuniqueclassmembernames

# These options produce useful stacktraces preserving line numbers
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# Pdf viewer
-keep class com.shockwave.**
-keep class com.media365ltd.doctime.networking.retrofit_latest.**

#agora
-keep class io.agora.**{*;}


# Amazon Chime
-keep class com.amazonaws.** { *; }# JSR 305 annotations are for embedding nullability information.
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**

                                   # A resource is loaded with a relative path so the package of this class must be preserved.
                                   -adaptresourcefilenames okhttp3/internal/publicsuffix/PublicSuffixDatabase.gz

                                   # Animal Sniffer compileOnly dependency to ensure APIs are compatible with older versions of Java.
                                   -dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.*

                                   # OkHttp platform used only on JVM and when Conscrypt and other security providers are available.
                                   -dontwarn okhttp3.internal.platform.**
                                   -dontwarn org.conscrypt.**
                                   -dontwarn org.bouncycastle.**
                                   -dontwarn org.openjsse.**


# Adjust
-keep class com.adjust.sdk.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult {
    int SUCCESS;
}
-keep class com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient {
    com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient$Info getAdvertisingIdInfo(android.content.Context);
}
-keep class com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient$Info {
    java.lang.String getId();
    boolean isLimitAdTrackingEnabled();
}
-keep public class com.android.installreferrer.** { *; }
```

Any insight is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey there, I've encountered a similar issue with the Agora SDK after updating to its latest version. The problem persists in a signed build, throwing the same error as mentioned earlier. If you happen to find a solution for this, would you mind sharing the fix? Thanks!

Comment: I haven't found any solution yet. I had to downgrade my gradle version to 7.2.2. This is something only Agora can fix from their end.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar error after upgrading from Agora RTC version v3.0.0.2 to v4.2.6 (the latest version). The error occurred specifically during the generation of the signed APK. Fortunately, I found a solution to this issue.

Contrary to some suggestions, I found that adding the line below to Proguard rules isn't necessary (provided you are using Flamingo 2022.2.1 Patch 1 or a higher version):

```
-dontwarn com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
```

Instead, what resolved the problem for me was including this line:

```
-dontwarn io.agora.**
```

For context, my Gradle Plugin Version (AGP) is 8.1.2 and Gradle Version is 8.3.

This adjustment helped successfully mitigate the issue I encountered during the signed APK build process after upgrading the Agora RTC version.

Hope this helps others facing a similar problem!